# Is it possible to encoding a linked .js file in UTF-8 in itself?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, special-characters

Dear JavaScript masters,

Does someone knows if it is possible to encode a .js in UTF-8 inside itself?

I'm asking this because i've got some words that use special characters like "João" and "sítio", and i can't use "&atilde" and "&iacute".

(If you need to know my text editor is Sublime Text)

Regards, 
João Santos

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. with "enconding a .js in UTF-8 inside itself"

Comment: If i can encode the file in UTF-8 inside it. I don´t want to encode the UTF-8 inside the .html file, but in the .js file.

Comment: Sure you can! Just save it in your editor with that encoding, and instruct your webserver to send the right header announcing that encoding.